# Full calendar está passando o footer do site

Tags: css, fullcalendar

insira o código aquiComo mostrado na imagem abaixo, o fullcalendar ao clicar em "mais" passa o meu rodapé quando na verdade ele deveria empurrar ele para baixo aumentando a altura da pagina, como acontece com todas as outras telas. Qual elemento css poderia usar para corrigir esse problema? Já tentei usar clearfix, mexer no z-index, mas não deu certo... Posso ter feito o uso incorreto dele. Uso o template INSPINIA vendido no Wrapbootstrap e ele é de muita qualidade.

Código:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Agenda</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div id="calendar" class="animated"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="footer text-center">
        <div>
            <strong>SoftTooth™ 0.3.0-Beta</strong> - 2014-2015 Todos os direitos reservados. By <a>Allan Carvalho</a> e <a>Eduardo Luciano</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .footer {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Alguem ajuda?

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione mais informações à pergunta e algum código onde você já tenha tentado alguma coisa. Ajuda à quem quer te ajudar.

Comment: tente ver qual é o CSS que está a fazer o dialogo e aumento o `z-index` para 999 por exemplo... sem um código exemplo, nao consigo ajudar mais.

Comment: Adicionei o código. Conseguem agora? Obrigado desde ja!

Answer (score 1):

Seria necessário ver mesmo um exemplo online disto em funcionamento para ver e indicar uma solução em concreto, ou o que está a gerar este problema, no entanto tenho duas soluções para te ajudar com isto:

1. **Primeira solução** - Adicionar uma scrollbar.
   Na caixa onde diz **"31 de Agosto de 2015"**, dentro dela está um espaço em branco e logo de seguida os números (que penso que sejam horas) com um `background` verde.
   Clica na parte em branco com o botão direito do rato e **inspeciona o elemento** para descobrir qual é a class "*container/wrapper*" (ou `class pai` se preferires) que contem os demais números com o background verde, e adiciona a esse container os seguintes estilos CSS: `max-height: 100px; overflow-x: auto;`. O objectivo é evitar que ela se prolongue para além da footer adicionando uma scrollbar quando esta `div` é maior que `100px` (ou o tamanho que desejares).
   Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.horas {
    max-height: 100px;          /* Altura máxima da div */
    overflow-x: auto;           /* Adiciona Scrollbar quanto necessário */
    width: 60px;                /* Não Relevante */
    border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;  /* Não Relevante */
}
```

```html
<div class="horas">
    001<br/>
    002<br/>
    003<br/>
    004<br/>
    005<br/>
    006<br/>
    007<br/>
    008<br/>
    009<br/>
    010<br/>
    011<br/>
    012<br/>
    013<br/>
    014<br/>
    015<br/>
    016<br/>
    017<br/>
    018<br/>
    019<br/>
    020<br/>
</div>
```

2. **Segunda solução** - Utilizar `z-index`.
   Como já foi referido nos comentários acima pelo @balexandre, utilizar `z-index` irá fazer com que essa lista fique por cima do **footer** e não o contrário. Para descobrir qual a class para aplicar o `z-index`, segue o mesmo processo de inspecionar o elemento mencionado na **Primeira solução**, mas desta vez inspeciona mesmo o título **"31 de Agosto de 2015"** para descobrir qual é a `div class/id` acima deste título, que será a sua `class pai` que "encaixota" o titulo, as horas etc, e que será a class onde iremos aplicar o `z-index`. Exemplo abaixo:

```css
.wrapperHoras {
    z-index: 1;                 /* Faz com que as horas fiquem por cima do Footer - Aumenta este valor se for necessário */
    position: absolute;         /* pre-defenido */
    background: #fff;
    width: 60px;                /* Não Relevante */
    border: 2px solid #C6C6C6;  /* Não Relevante */
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #85CFF9;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperHoras">
    <div class="horas">
        001<br/>
        002<br/>
        003<br/>
        004<br/>
        005<br/>
        006<br/>
        007<br/>
        008<br/>
        009<br/>
        010<br/>
        011<br/>
        012<br/>
        013<br/>
        014<br/>
        015<br/>
        016<br/>
        017<br/>
        018<br/>
        019<br/>
        020<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Meu Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o seguinte, mude o `position:absolute` do footer para `relative`, e caso a div também esteja com esse valor altere-o, depois use um `clearfix` na `div` que envolve todo o conteudo, acredito que resolverá.